# Determine reaction forces on square frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

> The square frame consists of four identical homogeneous rods of mass $m$. It lies in the vertical plane and can move in it due to the wheels situated in A and B. These wheels can slide frictionlessly along the "white" horizontal and vertical tracks respectively. The frame is released from rest in the position as depicted above. The task is to determine the 
>   instantaneous reactions forces in A and B precisely when the frame is released.

---

Since the tracks are frictionless the (net) reaction force in B is strictly horizontal and in A strictly vertical. Below is my free-body diagram.

[image]
<sub>(source: [draw.to](http://draw.to/static/d/40Lzcj.png?v=5b4eb))</sub>

Let's begin with $\textbf{F} = m  \boldsymbol{a}_{\text{G}}$. We have

$$ m \boldsymbol{a}_{\text{G}} = (\text{N}_{\text{A}} - 4mg) \textbf{e}_y + \text{N}_{\text{B}} \textbf{e}_x \ . $$

Next we will use moment of inertia about an axis through the center of mass $\text{G}$, parallell to the $z$-axis (coming out from the screen). The moment of inertia about $G$ for the entire frame is $I_G = 16ml^2/3$. The torque then is

$$ I_G \dot{\omega} = l ( N_A - N_B) \ ,  $$

which will give us an expression for the angular acceleration (note that $\omega = 0$ in the instance of release).

---

This is unfortunately all the progress I've been able to make and I am really clueless as to how I should proceed from here. I think the equation for accelerations in a rigid body make come in handy

$$ \boldsymbol{a}_P = \boldsymbol{a}_Q + \dot{\omega} \textbf{e}_z \times \textbf{r}_{QP} - \underbrace{\omega^2}_0 \textbf{e}_z \ , $$

where $P$ and $Q$ are two points on the rigid body; the question is which points to choose judiciously. $G$ definitely is one of them but I have no information on the acceleration of any other point of the frame.

---

The answers:

$$ \textbf{N}_A = \frac {14}5 mg \textbf{e}_y , \quad \textbf{N}_B = \frac 65 mg \textbf{e}_x $$

Comment: This is a near problem. Converting the two sliders (two degrees of freedom) into a single degree of freedom problem is the key to solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you need to consider is the kinematics. That is what is the position, velocity and acceleration of the center of mass *G* as the frame rotates. I set the coordinate system origin where the two slots intersect to get

$$\begin{aligned} \vec{r}_A & = (x_A,0,0) & \vec{r}_B & = (0,y_B,0) \end{aligned} $$

The I recognized that the two positions are related by a rigid body transformation

$$ \vec{r}_B = \vec{r}_A + \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} - 2\ell \\ 2 \ell \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

which gives $x_A = 2 \ell (\cos \theta+\sin \theta)$ and $y_B = 2 \ell (\cos \theta-\sin \theta)$. So now we have the positions *A*, *B*, and *G* as a function of the rotation angle $\theta$.

$$\begin{aligned} 
 \vec{r}_A & = (2 \ell (\cos \theta+\sin \theta),0,0) \\
 \vec{r}_B & = (0,2 \ell (\cos \theta-\sin \theta),0) \\ 
 \vec{r}_G & = (\ell (\cos \theta+\sin \theta), \ell (\cos \theta-\sin \theta),0) 
\end{aligned} $$

More importantly we have the influence of the angle, which by using chain rule we get

$$\begin{aligned} 
 \vec{v}_A =(\dot{x}_A,0,0) & = (y_B \dot{\theta},0,0) \\
 \vec{v}_B =(0,\dot{y}_B,0) & = (0,-x_A \dot{\theta} ,0) \\ 
\end{aligned} $$

The velocity kinematics of the center of mass follow the rigid body rule

$$\begin{aligned} 
 \vec{v}_G & = \vec{v}_A + \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{r}_G - \vec{r}_A) \\
 \vec{v}_G =(\dot{x}_G,\dot{y}_G,0) & = (\frac{y_B}{2} \dot{\theta},-\frac{x_A}{2} \dot{\theta} ,0) \\
 \vec{\omega} & = (0,0,\dot{\theta})
\end{aligned} $$

and

$$\begin{aligned} 
 \vec{a}_A =(\ddot{x}_A,0,0) & = (y_B \ddot{\theta}-x_A \dot{\theta}^2,0,0) \\
 \vec{a}_B =(0,\ddot{y}_B,0) & = (0,-x_A \ddot{\theta}-y_A \dot{\theta}^2 ,0) \\ 
\end{aligned} $$

The acceleration kinematics of the center of mass follow the rigid body rule

$$\begin{aligned} 
 \vec{a}_G & = \vec{a}_A +\dot{\vec{\omega}}\times (\vec{r}_G - \vec{r}_A)+ \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{v}_G - \vec{v}_A) \\
 \vec{a}_G =(\ddot{x}_G,\ddot{y}_G,0) & = (\frac{y_B}{2} \ddot{\theta}-\frac{x_A}{2} \dot{\theta}^2,-\frac{x_A}{2} \ddot{\theta}+\frac{y_B}{2} \dot{\theta}^2 ,0) 
\end{aligned} $$

Now we can look at sum of forces and moments about *G*

$$\begin{aligned} 
 \vec{N}_A + \vec{N}_B & = 4 m \vec{a}_G \\
 (\vec{r}_A-\vec{r}_G) \times \vec{N}_A +(\vec{r}_B-\vec{r}_G) \times \vec{N}_B & = I \dot{\vec{\omega}}
\end{aligned} $$

which expanded out by component yields the following system of 3 equations.

$$\begin{aligned} 
  N_B & = 4 m \ddot{x}_G =4 m \left(\frac{y_B}{2} \ddot{\theta}-\frac{x_A}{2} \dot{\theta}^2\right)  \\
  N_A-4 m g & =4  m \ddot{y}_G  =4 m \left(-\frac{x_A}{2} \ddot{\theta}+\frac{y_B}{2} \dot{\theta}^2 \right)\\
  N_A \frac{x_A}{2} - N_B \frac{y_A}{2} & = I_z \ddot{\theta}
\end{aligned} $$

where $I_z = \frac{16}{3} m \ell^2$

The answer is found when $\theta=0$, $\dot\theta=0$, $x_A=2 \ell$ and $y_B=2 \ell$ since the above is 3 equations with 3 unknowns ($N_A$, $N_B$ and $\ddot{\theta}$). The solution I get is

$$ \begin{aligned}
N_A & = \frac{g 4 m (I_z+4 m \ell^2)}{I_z+8 m \ell^2}  = \frac{14 m g}{5}\\
N_B & = \frac{g 16 m^2 \ell^2}{I_z + 8 m \ell^2} = \frac{6 m g}{5} \\
\ddot{\theta} &= \frac{g 4 m \ell}{I_z + 8 m \ell^2} = \frac{3 g}{10 \ell}
\end{aligned} $$

The answer here what you expect.

Comment: Sorry - no. The answer key is correct. You made a mistake.

Comment: What I did wrong is $m$ which for me is the _total_ mass of the 4 rods. Hence the $I_z$ and $m$ is not correct above.

Comment: That doesn't explain the discrepancy. $F_B=\frac37 F_A$ regardless of the mass. You get $F_B=\frac{3}{19}F_A$... there's something else going on.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The method was correct, I just assumed a different mass variable.

Comment: It is sufficient to just change $m \rightarrow 4m$ you also need to have consistent $I_z$. You need to make the substitution before the value of $I_z = \frac{16}{3} m  \ell^2$ is used since it contains the rod mass, and not the _net_ mass.

Comment: Well you seem to have come to the same answer now. Two approaches. I must admit that without a diagram it may not be easy for OP to understand how you arrive at your matrix expression - and why you are writing a 3D solution for a 2D problem.

Comment: It turns out planar kinematics and dynamics are easiest to write down if you just project a 3D problem into a plane (all $z$ values are zero). This makes sure the equations are consistent (instead of doing a 2D cross product).

Comment: Your solution is quite good and intuitive considering my level of knowledge. I just need to understand how $\theta$ is placed with respect to the body and the cooridnate system!

Comment: $\theta$ is a counter-clockwise rotation of the frame. The higher the $\theta$ the lower _B_ is and the further away _A_ is. You can see this by doing a small angle approximation $$x_A \approx 2 \ell (\theta+1) \\ y_A \approx 2 \ell (1-\theta) $$

Comment: But the coordinate system, is its origin fixed in the bottom left corner and are the directions of the systems axes fixed? Because I don't see why $\vec{r}_A$ has no components in the y-direction. Also, is $\theta$ the angle between the x-axis and the lower rod?

Comment: I don't see why $\vec{r}_A$ lies on the x-axis (since it only has a component in the x-direction) throughout the entire rotation.

Comment: I put the coordinate system origin where the two sliders intersect. So _A_ has only $x$ axis component, and _B_ only $y$ axis.

Comment: Right but what happens when the frame rotates a bit? For example say $\theta = \pi / 4$. Then $\vec{r}_A = (2 \sqrt 2 l,0,0)$ and $\vec{r}_B =  (0,0,0)$. How does $\vec{r}_B$ end up at the origin here: http://draw.to/D3VMGTZ

Comment: Put _B_ at the origin, and _A_ along the $x$ axis, with the center of the frame also along the $x$ axis. What you drew is incorrect because you are pivoting about the lower left corner. The center of rotation is similar to http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88597/392

Comment: See http://i.imgur.com/r53xsHo.png

Comment: ja72: Thanks, your drawing there helped me understand it!

Comment: Is not $y_A$ zero for all $t$?

Answer (score 1):

Draw the position of the frame a very small time later. From this you can determine the relative rotation (due to torque - the difference between the forces multiplied by their perpendicular distance to the center of gravity) and linear acceleration (due to net horizontal and vertical forces). That should give you all the equations you need and you can then solve for $F_A$ and $F_B$.

**A few hours later...**

Here is the diagram I had in mind - drawing a "large" $\theta$ because it's easier to see what is going on:

[image]

The distance $D=L\sqrt{2}$ is a convenient quantity to help compute the new position (x,y) at time t.

Next we need to calculate the moment of inertia of the square: from the parallel axis theorem, we find it is

$$I = 4(\frac{1}{12}m(2L)^2 + mL^2)=\frac{16}{3} mL^2$$

Now we have the following equations of motion:

$$4m\ddot{x}=F_B\\
4m\ddot{y}=4mg-F_A\\
I\ddot{\theta}=(F_B-F_A)L$$

And finally, when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ (start of motion) we can write

$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=D\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) = L\\
\frac{dx}{d\theta}=-D\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = -L$$

This means

$$\ddot{x}=-L\ddot{\theta}\\
\ddot{y}=L\ddot{\theta}$$

We can now eliminate $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{y}$ and are left with three equations in three unknowns:

$$4mL\ddot{\theta}=-F_B \tag1$$
$$4mL\ddot{\theta}=4mg-F_A \tag2$$
$$\frac{16}{3} m L \ddot{\theta} = F_A-F_B \tag3$$

Subtracting $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives

$$4mg=F_A+F_B\tag{4}$$

and $(1) - \frac34 (3)$ gives

$$F_B=\frac34(F_A-F_B)$$
$$F_B=\frac37 F_A\tag{5}$$

$(5)$ into $(4)$ gives

$$4mg = \frac{10}{7} F_A\\
F_A = \frac{14}{5} mg$$

and then it follows that

$$F_B = \frac65 mg$$

Just as your answer key showed.

Comment: Hi. "Draw the position of the frame a very small time later", I can't say I'm sure how to interpret. Infinitesimally small time later or enough time so it looks slanted? Also I can't say I'm fully aware what further information/equations this provides. Could you give some further hints? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The only thing confusing for me is that a positive $\theta$ is a clockwise rotation which means that a negative torque is needed to increase $\theta$. This makes it difficult to ensure consistency.

Comment: It was convenient to draw that particular angle. Sorry it was confusing!

Comment: Why is not the center of mass force 4mg considered in the torque equation $I \ddot{\theta}$ ?

Comment: @larrydavid: Force acting through the center of mass does not provide torque - the perpendicular distance of the force vector to the center of mass is zero.

Comment: Oh ok so it was the torque through the center of mass, did not realize that. 
From what coordinate system is the motion observed? Are you putting the origin of the stationary coordinate system at the bottom left corner of the square (at its initial rest position)? If so, how does those equations for x and y accurately describe the position of the center of mass. Those equations are for circle of a radius D and I don't think the square makes a circular motion about that corner. Thanks for the help, gettign a much better grip on this!

Comment: Also is not the the torque exerted by F_B negative and the one by F_A positive? You seem to have put it the other way around. I am assuming the axis about G is perpendicular out from the screen.

Comment: See ja72's earlier comment. My convention for $\theta$ is "unconventional" - it is measured clockwise, and it's 45° when the square starts out. Hence the torques seem to be backwards. By the way - I am pretty sure that the c.o.m. _does_ describe a circle about the bottom left corner (but only a piece of it, since $\theta=45°$ at the start of the motion).

Comment: Ah ok! How subtle indeed that $\theta$ was unconventionally oriented. Quite complex and unintuitive stuff to digest here, I'll have to give it some time and thought. Thanks for all help

Comment: What are your positive x and y directions? For the net force you have written $- F_B$ and $4mg - F_A$, instead of the other way around.

Comment: X and Y are in the conventional directions. The signs are backwards because the rotation is. You will see the sign the other way around higher up ($m\ddot{x}=F_B$ etc).

Comment: If it is conventional then we must have negative $4mg$ because it is directed downwards and y is upwards. Confusing