# Leaning ladder reaction force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics

Shouldn't the reaction force by the ground act along the direction of the ladder?  under what conditions will it be along the ladder. What causes the direction of reaction force to not act along ladder?
[image]

Comment: Note that with only these three forces acting on the ladder which is in equilibrium the lines of action of the three forces must meet at a point.  This can be used to find the direction of force $R_2$.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88597/392

Comment: Why do you think  the reaction force at the ground **should** act along the ladder? What is different with the reaction at the wall? Why doesn't that reaction force have to act along the ladder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a statics problem, a surface (wall or ground) can only produce a normal force (perpendicular to the surface) and a static friction force (along the surface), where both of those forces are whatever they need to be to prevent movement into or along the surface (and remember that the static friction force has a maximum value).  So this means the sum of those two forces is a single force that prevents movement, so can point in any direction necessary (though without glue, it could not point inward into the surface).  So it doesn't matter what direction the ladder points, the force from the surface does not need to point along the ladder.   Indeed, the problem of a ladder against the wall is insufficiently constrained unless you make the wall smooth so there is only a normal force from the wall-- if there is static friction along the wall, you can have many different answers if the ladder is squeezed into place.   So without static friction on the wall, the force from the wall is horizontal, and the force from the ground is whatever it needs to be.