# Infinity problem in basic classical mechanics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, singularities, constrained-dynamics

My question arises from a classical mechanics problem from a Hong Kong physics training programme:

[image]

**This is not a homework question as I am not asking about how to solve the problems in the image.**

As an additional exercise, I tried to solve for $\alpha$ as a function of $t$.

From energy conservation,

$$\frac{m\dot x^2}2+\frac{m\dot y^2}2+mgy=mgy_0$$

By the substitution $x=L\cos\alpha, y=L\sin\alpha$, we have

$$\frac{L}{2g}\dot\alpha^2=\sin\alpha_0-\sin\alpha$$

Rearranging immediately gives
$$\int^\alpha_{\alpha_0}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin\alpha_0-\sin\theta}}=-\int^t_0\sqrt{\frac{2g}{L}}dt$$

(Negative square root is taken as $\dot\alpha<0$.)

---

If we naively substitute in $\alpha_0=\frac{\pi}2$, then the integral diverges. This makes sense as a vertical rod should stand still.

---

I guess that taking the limit $\alpha_0\to\frac\pi2^-$ would avoid the infinity problem, but I have no idea how can this be implemented.

How can I avoid the divergence and obtain $\alpha(t)$?

Comment: Hi Szeto. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, the initial setup (i.e. bodies static and rod perfectly vertical) is a valid solution of the equations of motion for all times. Since the system is unstable, you can either add a small deviation from the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ angle or a small amount of initial kinetic energy, to branch out from the static solution and find a different one with the rod falling.

Comment: Related [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88597/392) to this problem.