# Finding accelerations using Instantaneous axis of rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics

**Disclaimer: I present a question which is homework-like, However it is simply to demonstrate an example. I only wish to clarify one thing, that is the validity of the IAR in determining the accelerations.**

IAR: stands for the *Instantaneous Axis of Rotation*

Consider a Massless rod (initially vertical) with two Balls A and B of the same mass $m$ attached at the two ends. A slides along a frictionless wall, B slides along a frictionless floor.
[image]

**My interpretation of the IAR: at the "instant", the system can be thought of as rotating *purely* about the IAR.**'

I have used this interpretation of the IAR a lot: and have successfully managed to tackle quite a few problems by  representing the entire kinetic energy of the system as $1/2I_{iar}\omega^2$, or even (**sometimes**) use $\tau _{iar}=I_{iar}\alpha$. However, **accelerations** aren't modelled property by this interpretation.

For instance, in the diagram above, the interpretation suggests that:
$\vec{A_a}$=$(\omega ^2(l\cos(\theta)))\hat{i}$-$(\alpha(l\cos(\theta)))\hat{j}$.

However, $x_a$=0 always. So $\ddot{x_a}$=$0$, and thus we have a contradiction. Likewise for B.

Things get more bizarre when you consider the instant when A **leaves the wall**.

My observations: This happens at $\sin(\theta)=2/3$, and at this instant,$\ddot{x_b}$=$0$ ,$\ddot{y_b}$=$0$, $\ddot{x_a}$=$0$ and $\ddot{y_a}$=$-g\hat{j}$. This cannot be explained by the IAR *at all* which leads to my question: **When is it appropriate to say that  $\vec{A}$=-$(\omega ^2(r)\hat{n}$+$(\alpha(r))\hat{\theta}$., where r is the distance from IAR?**

Comment: The formatting of this post, and also the inconsistent spacing and capitalization make it hard to read (at least for me). For instance: Why is there a bunch of capital "The"s in the middle of sentences? Why is there sometimes a space after commas and sometimes not? Why are some sentences and words bold? Please also consider spelling out an abbreviation (IAR) at least once in the body of a post.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks a lot for your comments. Ill be careful with the formatting the next time I post a question.

Comment: I am tempted to believe that instead of $-(\omega ^2 r)\hat{n}$+$(\alpha r)\hat{\theta}$,  I should instead have $(\ddot{r}-\omega ^2 r)\hat{n}$+$(2\omega\dot{r}+\alpha r)\hat{\theta}$.

Comment: One problem with your formulas,  You do not know, ω.

Comment: Total kinetic energy= $1/2I_{iar}\omega^2.$. We can Use conservation of mechanical energy To find $\omega$ as a function of $\theta$.

Comment: And anyways, knowing /not knowing $\omega$ is irrelevant to the fact that We encounter a *contradiction* when we try to equate the acceleration to $\omega^2 r$

Comment: Conservation of energy will work if you know or assume a starting point. By the way, there is no contradiction with having a centripetal acceleration for an object which is instantaneously moving on a circular path. (The radius is not changing.    As mass, A, moves down the center of rotation moves down with it.)

Comment: I state clearly, "For instance, in the diagram above, the interpretation suggests that:
$\vec{A_a}$=$(\omega ^2(l\cos(\theta)))\hat{i}$-$(\alpha(l\cos(\theta)))\hat{j}$."

Comment: And i also state: "but for A, $x=0$ always, and thus $\ddot{x_a}=0$." The two statements *clearly* imply $(\omega ^2(l\cos(\theta)))=0$

Comment: How about this: The connecting rod is under compression, and exerts a horizontal component of force on mass, A, which prevents the horizontal  acceleration.

Comment: you are still not getting my point i am afraid. Your statement (which is correct) , explains why $\ddot{x_a}$=0. My question was why is it not =$\omega^2r$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88597/392

Comment: @ja72 your answer is excellent as always.And i was able to figure out the acceleration vector(s) of A and B by writing $y=lsin(\theta)$ and $x=cos(\theta)$., and by differentiating this twice.However, why can we not say that its =$\omega^2r?$and $r alpha$? since that's the acceleration components for circular motion.

Comment: x_a>0 and y_b>0

Comment: @cumfy what? A is slides on the wall, b slides on the floor. x_a=0 and y_b=0.

Answer (score 8):

This is a good question, and highlights a common misconception in Newtonian mechanics. For concreteness, let's work in two dimensions.

It's true that at every moment, you can write the *velocity* as a rotation about an instantaneous point $\mathbf{r}_0$ of rotation, which means that the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ of any point in the body satisfies
$$\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_0).$$
The derivative is the acceleration, so there are three terms by the product rule, because of the three places the derivative can act,
$$\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{\alpha} \times (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_0) + \omega \times \mathbf{v} - \omega \times \mathbf{v}_0.$$
The first term represents the angular acceleration. The second term represents the usual centripetal acceleration due to rotation. And the third term is due to the rate of change $\mathbf{v}_0 = d\mathbf{r}_0/dt$ of the instantaneous point of rotation $\mathbf{r}_0$ itself. That's the term you're missing. Your statement in bold is correct exactly when this term vanishes.

Almost all introductory physics textbooks ignore this term, because they work with only simple situations where $\mathbf{v}_0 = 0$, but it is there. For example, I wrote [question B3 on the 2019 US Physics Olympiad](https://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/2020/upload/2019_USAPhO.pdf) with the sole purpose of illustrating this point; in that problem the instantaneous point of rotation is changing, and without accounting for this, one gets incorrect physical answers.

Comment: In my problem,(rod with balls sliding), The instantaneous point of rotation, at each instant is a point in the air, at rest. The point is different at each instant: but whatever it is, it is at rest

Comment: @satan29 Sure, I didn't mean that the instantaneous point of rotation was physically moving, because there isn't anything there at all. I just meant that it's changing in time -- because of that, it must contribute another term to the acceleration by the product rule.

Comment: @satan29 To put it another way, if you agree with my first equation, then the second equation just follows from the definition of differentiation.

Comment: @satan29 But it's not true that $\mathbf{v}_0 = 0$. Try drawing where $\mathbf{r}_0$ is in your problem, and then where it is a moment later. It's not the same point. So because $\mathbf{v}_0$ is defined as $d \mathbf{r}_0 / dt$, it's nonzero.

Comment: Oh gosh, I see it now.

Comment: I tried to extend your analysis to torques.I was trying to write a comment, but it was too large for a comment, and so I decided to write it as a question, do have a look: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557285/analysing-tau-i-alpha-about-the-instantaneous-axis-of-rotation

Answer (score 4):

If you work out the problem, you will find that the acceleration on the end is just tangent to the walls. This is true for a solid body, or for two masses attached to a rigid link between them.

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{a}_{\rm K} & = \pmatrix{ 0 \\ -L \omega^2 \cos \varphi - L \dot \omega \sin \varphi } \\
\vec{a}_{\rm H} & = \pmatrix{L \dot \omega \cos \varphi - L \omega^2 \sin \varphi \\ 0} \end{aligned}  \tag{1}$$

[image: pic1]

There is no horizontal component of $\vec{a}_{\rm K}$ and no vertical component of $\vec{a}_{\rm H}$. And this makes sense since points **K** and **H** are each kinematically linked to their sliding action.

When you find the acceleration vector for each point in space, you can find the location **B** where the acceleration is zero. That is the instant axis of acceleration (IAA) and according to my calculations, it is always down and to the left of IAR. When the body isn't moving (initially) then the IAA is on top of the IAR.

The center of rotation is found to be at

$$ \begin{aligned} x_{\rm A} & = L  \sin \varphi & y_{\rm A} & = L \cos \varphi \end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

The center of acceleration is found to be at

$$ \begin{aligned} x_{\rm B} & = L \left( \frac{6 \sin \varphi}{5-3 \cos \varphi} - \sin \varphi \right) & y_{\rm B} & = \left( \frac{9 \sin^2 \varphi}{2(5-3 \cos \varphi)} - \frac{\sin^2 \varphi}{2(\cos \varphi-1)} \right) \end{aligned} \tag{3}$$

This is using the following solution of two separated masses

$$ \begin{aligned} \dot \omega & = \frac{g}{L} \sin \varphi & \omega^2 = \frac{2 g ( 1-\cos \varphi)}{L} \end{aligned} \tag{4} $$

But the result is the same as using a thin rod and

$$ \begin{aligned} \dot \omega & = \frac{3 g}{2 L} \sin \varphi & \omega^2 = \frac{3 g ( 1-\cos \varphi)}{L} \end{aligned} \tag{5} $$

<sub>Interesting things happen at $\varphi \approx 48.19^\circ$ making $\vec{a}_{\rm H}=0$.</sub>

**Why isn't there an acceleration towards the IAR on the endpoints?**

Although the body is rotating about IAR, it is also accelerating downwards and to the right. This means that the IAR is moving with time and the acceleration of the body @IAR isn't zero it is $$ \vec{a}_{\rm IAR} = \pmatrix{ 2 g \sin\varphi \cos \varphi -2 g \sin \varphi \\ 2 g \cos^2 \varphi -2 g \cos \varphi} \tag{6}$$

<sub>Note the above isn't the acceleration of the IAR as that would be meaningless, but the acceleration of the body at the IAR.</sub>

**It is *exactly* such as so the body does not violate the kinematics (sliding joints) in the future.**

Answer (score 2):

your system has one generalized coordinate $\varphi$

thus:

$$x=L\sin \left( \varphi  \right)$$
$$y=L\cos \left( \varphi  \right) $$

with:

$$T=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)$$

and

$$U=m\,g\,y$$

you get:

$$\ddot{\varphi}=\frac{g}{L}\,\sin(\varphi)\tag 1$$

the velocity vector is :
$$\vec{v}= \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{ \varphi}\,y \\
  -\dot{\varphi}\,x \\
\end{bmatrix}=\dot{\varphi}\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} L\cos \left( \varphi  \right)  
\\ -L\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \
\end {array} \right] 
\tag 2$$

the time derivative of equation (2) is the acceleration vector:

$$\vec{a}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -L\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \dot{\varphi }^{
2}+\ddot{\varphi}\,L\cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\ -L\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \dot{\varphi }^{2}-
\ddot{\varphi} \,L\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

and with equation (1)

$$\vec{a}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -L\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \dot{\varphi }^{
2}+[\frac{g}{L}\,\sin(\varphi)]\,L\cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\ -L\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \dot{\varphi }^{2}-
[\frac{g}{L}\,\sin(\varphi)] \,L\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

**edit**

[image]

I) acceleration point A and B

the velocity of $m_1$ is:
$$\vec{v}_A=v_A\vec{\hat{e}}_y=-\omega\,X\,\vec{\hat{e}}_y$$

the velocity of $m_2$ is:
$$\vec{v}_B=v_B\vec{\hat{e}}_x=\omega\,Y\,\vec{\hat{e}}_x$$

with :

$X=L\sin(\varphi)\quad,Y=L\cos(\varphi)\quad$ and $\omega=\dot{\varphi}$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
  v_A \\
  v_B \\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\vec{\omega}\times \vec{R}_p\tag A$$

where :

$$\vec{R}_p=\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  Y \\
  0\\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,\vec{\omega}=\dot{\varphi}\,\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
  1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

acceleration

$$\vec{a}=\begin{bmatrix}
  a_A \\
  a_B \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}=\vec{\dot{\omega}}\times \vec{R}_p+
\vec{\omega}\times \vec{\dot{R}}_p\tag B$$

where

$$\vec{\dot{R}}_p=\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{X} \\
  \dot{Y} \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

II) acceleration arbitrary point $u$ of the rod

velocity of point u is:

$$\vec{v}_u=\vec{\omega}\,\times \vec{u}$$

where:

$$\vec{u}=\vec{R}_u-\vec{R}_p$$
and
$$\vec{R}_u=\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
 y(x) \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
 -\frac{Y}{X}\,x+Y \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,0\le x\le X
$$

to "move" the point u on the rod you substitute $x\mapsto a_u\,X$ to $\vec{R}_u$

thus

$$\vec{R}_u=\begin{bmatrix}
  a_u\,X \\
 -\frac{Y}{X}\,a\,X+Y \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  a_u\,X \\
 -a_u\,Y+Y \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,0\le a_u\le 1$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
  a_u\,X \\
 -a_u\,Y+Y \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  Y \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  X\,(a_u-1) \\
  -a_u\,Y \\
  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,0\le a_u\le 1$$

Acceleration:

$$\vec{A}_u=\vec{\dot{\omega}}\times \vec{u}+
\vec{\omega}\times \vec{\dot{u}}=\ddot{\varphi}\,L\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \varphi  \right) a_u
\\\sin \left( \varphi  \right)  \left( a_u-1 \right) 
\\0\end {array} \right] +\dot{\varphi}^2\,L\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} -a_u\,\sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
\\ \cos \left( \varphi  \right)  \left( a_u-1 \right) 
\\ 0\end {array} \right] 
\tag C$$

**Simulation:**

With equation (1) you get $\ddot{\varphi}$ and the solution of the differential equation $\varphi(t)$

the position vector to the IAR point is $$\vec{R}_p=\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
 Y \\
\end{bmatrix}=L\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin(\varphi(t) \\
\cos(\varphi(t) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I stop the simulation when the Y coordinate is zero.

[image: Figure 1]

Figure  1

The  trajectory of the IAR points (blue points) and the position of the rod.

[image]

Figure 2

The trajectory of the  acceleration components $\vec{A}_u$ for three different rod points

Answer (score -1):

The weight of mass, A , produces a torque about the center of rotation: (mgL)cosθ = Iα  solving gives α = (g/L)cosθ (counter-clockwise).  Multiplying by the corresponding radii gives the negative y acceleration for mass, A, = -g (cosθ)^2  and x acceleration for mass, B, = g(sinθ)(cosθ).
The x acceleration for the center of mass is half that of mass, B;  (H/2m) = (1/2)g(sinθ)(cosθ)  Solving gives the horizontal force from the left hand wall; H = mg(sinθ)(cosθ)  A similar calculation gives the upward vertical force from the lower surface; V = 2mg – mg(cosθ)^2.  If these calculations are correct, mass, A, does not leave the wall before striking the lower surface.

Answer (score -1):

instantaneous rotation point is a point where velocity of that point at that point is zero but while you are write acceleration in iaor point you try to see that acceleration work in ground frame which is incorrect you have add acceleration of pseudo force and then you see acceleration of A in ground frame in y direction is zero so in conclusion iaor is point where velocity at that instant is zero not acceleration. $\alpha$ and $\omega$ remain same in all frames and don't change.
Let me know if this is incorrect.

Comment: The "point" is in in the air, and is not accelerating. So we wont need a pseudo force.

Comment: I'm not talking of point in air I am saying iaor has acceleration

Comment: See as rod slides iaor moves

Comment: yes. But its not like there is *one* axis thats  accelerating:at each instant, The IAR changes. but at each instant, the IAR is an axis passing through a point that is at rest. Theres no acceleration.

Comment: having a different iar at each instant is not equivalent to saying "iar is accelerating". At each instant, The Iar is different, but whatever it is, its not accelerating

Comment: Heres a different example: Consider the classic case of a ring rolling without slipping. The IAR will pass through a bottom point. Now, here, The IAR is accelerating: at each instant the IAR has an acceleration $\omega^2r$ upwards.

Comment: Ok I will re answer the question

Comment: @satan I just want to ask why acceleration of iar is meaningless